# Error: invalid address upon calling balanceof() function of token inspite of setting default account and unlocking

Tags: balances

Can someone please shed light on what I might be doing wrong here? I'm trying to query the token balance of an account using geth (v1.7.2) and I'm doing the following but I get invalid address even though the address is correct of both the address and the token.

The following are the steps im doing.

Thanks for your help.

#### Set default account

```
> web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

"0x41f32f70119e9deead9681d371207cae0b2c16f6"
```

#### Unlock Account

```
> web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0], "PASSWORD", 3600);

true
```

#### Set Token's ABI

```
> tokenabi = web3.eth.contract([{"constant": "true","inputs": [{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name": "","type": "uint256"}],"payable":"false","stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);

{
  abi: [{
      constant: "true",
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "balanceOf",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: "false",
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }],
  eth: {
    accounts: ["0x41f32f70119e9deead9681d371207cae0b2c16f6", "0x77ca2e7e9aa9f0494560ed0eacbe1b1b90f9fcb6"],
    blockNumber: 10887,
    coinbase: "0x41f32f70119e9deead9681d371207cae0b2c16f6",
    compile: {
      lll: function(),
      serpent: function(),
      solidity: function()
    },
    defaultAccount: "0x41f32f70119e9deead9681d371207cae0b2c16f6",
    defaultBlock: "latest",
    gasPrice: 0,
    hashrate: 0,
    mining: false,
    pendingTransactions: [],
    protocolVersion: "0x3f",
    syncing: false,
    call: function(),
    contract: function(abi),
    estimateGas: function(),
    filter: function(options, callback, filterCreationErrorCallback),
    getAccounts: function(callback),
    getBalance: function(),
    getBlock: function(),
    getBlockNumber: function(callback),
    getBlockTransactionCount: function(),
    getBlockUncleCount: function(),
    getCode: function(),
    getCoinbase: function(callback),
    getCompilers: function(),
    getGasPrice: function(callback),
    getHashrate: function(callback),
    getMining: function(callback),
    getPendingTransactions: function(callback),
    getProtocolVersion: function(callback),
    getRawTransaction: function(),
    getRawTransactionFromBlock: function(),
    getStorageAt: function(),
    getSyncing: function(callback),
    getTransaction: function(),
    getTransactionCount: function(),
    getTransactionFromBlock: function(),
    getTransactionReceipt: function(),
    getUncle: function(),
    getWork: function(),
    iban: function(iban),
    icapNamereg: function(),
    isSyncing: function(callback),
    namereg: function(),
    resend: function(),
    sendIBANTransaction: function(),
    sendRawTransaction: function(),
    sendTransaction: function(),
    sign: function(),
    signTransaction: function(),
    submitTransaction: function(),
    submitWork: function()
  },
  at: function(address, callback),
  getData: function(),
  new: function()
}
```

#### Define Token Instance

```
> tokeninst = tokenabi.at(0xd27716ebAdDaE1902C45878803A5c3582426ada3);

{
  abi: [{
      constant: "true",
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "balanceOf",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: "false",
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }],
  address: 1.201543847219371e+48,
  transactionHash: null,
  allEvents: function(),
  balanceOf: function()
}
```

#### Validate Address with Balance

```
> web3.isAddress("0x41f32f70119e9deead9681d371207cae0b2c16f6");

true
```

#### Validate Token Contract Address

```
> web3.isAddress("0xd27716ebAdDaE1902C45878803A5c3582426ada3");

true
```

#### Query Balance of Address

```
> balance = tokeninst.balanceOf.call("0x41f32f70119e9deead9681d371207cae0b2c16f6");


**Error: invalid address**
    at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:3734:22
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at web3.js:4102:22
    at <anonymous>:1:11
```

Have also tried it with

```
> balance = tokeninst.balanceOf("0x41f32f70119e9deead9681d371207cae0b2c16f6");


**Error: invalid address**
    at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:3734:22
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at web3.js:4102:22
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4227:12
```

What do you reckon is wrong / missing here with my steps ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is missing quotes:

```
tokeninst = tokenabi.at(0xd27716ebAdDaE1902C45878803A5c3582426ada3);
```

Try this instead:

```
tokeninst = tokenabi.at("0xd27716ebAdDaE1902C45878803A5c3582426ada3");
```

Comment: I was just thinking the same, but why does it give the correct ABI if the address was malformed :(

Comment: The ABI was passed in correctly, so why wouldn't it be correct? Note that `tokenabi` is a misnomer, since it's a contract object. And note that the `address` field in the return value of `tokenabi.at` is a number.

Comment: great spotting , that was it , when passing token name without quotes it was still returning an output without an error however the difference is when passing it with quotes  it returns the address of the token as shown in the output below. thanks heaps.

{
  abi: [{
      constant: "true",
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "balanceOf",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: "false",
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }],
  address: "0xd27716ebAdDaE1902C45878803A5c3582426ada3",
  transactionHash: null,
  allEvents: function(),
  balanceOf: function()
}